# How can I find an unused TCP port in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to launch a process and tell it to use an unused TCP port. Unfortunately, the binary I'm starting won't probe for an unused port. Is there a decent way for me to probe ports in Dart so I can use that as an argument to my process?

The best I can think of is to create a `ServerSocket` with a port of 0, and then close the socket and use it's port, but this seems hacky to me.

Anyone have a better way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll add my 'hack' as an answer because I can't think of another way, and it seems to work pretty well.

Here's my `getUnusedPort()` function:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

Future<int> getUnusedPort(InternetAddress address) {
  return ServerSocket.bind(address ?? InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 0).then((socket) {
    var port = socket.port;
    socket.close();
    return port;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above is racy since another process can reclaim the port once the socket is closed. Use the pattern in https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/dart-lang/test/+/master/pkgs/test_core/lib/src/util/io.dart#147

```
Future<T> getUnusedPort<T>(FutureOr<T> Function(int port) tryPort) async {
  T value;
  await Future.doWhile(() async {
    value = await tryPort(await getUnsafeUnusedPort());
    return value == null;
  });
  return value;
}
```